# Java - jFrame Listeners

Tags: java, jframe, listeners

I am trying to make it so when a person starts to type in a textfield it will instantly start to put that text at the end of another textfield. I will be using this for a file path.

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: @Henrik I am basically trying to figure out how I can take text that is entered into one textfield, and add it to another simultaneously.  I believe Haloboy has solved my problem, but I still need to test it.

Answer (score 1):

To detect and track changes to the text content of a JTextfield, you have to add a DocumentListener to the document of the JTextField.

Please see this Oracle Tutorial:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html